Using a syncfusion ejs-dropdownlist inside a bootstrap modal
I have a ejs-dropdownlist component inside a bootstrap modal but the bs.focustrap handler is preventing the user from typing into the filter textbox in the dropdownlist.
The dropdownlist opens and you can select items by clicking on them but if you click on the filter input box, it immediately loses focus.
If I use the Edge Dev Tools to delete the bs.focustrap handler from the focusin event, the filter will work as it's meant to.
Looking at the DOM, it seems Syncfusion create all the elements for the expanded dropdown, including the filter inputbox, at the end of the DOM and thus outside the scope of the modal that bootstrap is trying to keep focus within.
Is there any workaround for this?
I'm using Vue 3.3.4, Bootstrap 5.2.3 and syncfusion/ej2-vue-dropdowns 25.2.5
